# How can I use string interpolation within an anchor tag?

Tags: html, angular

```html
<a [href]="urlByEnvironment()">{{ 'main.flow-contact-link | translate' }}</a>
```

I need to create a hyperlink from text which is found in a Json file

I can't hardcode the text inside the anchor tag. I have used string interpolation from the same Json file elsewhere in the same template and it works fine, I just can't get it to work inside the anchor tag

Comment: remove the single quote. `{{ main.flow-contact-link | translate }}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to do that

```
<a [href]="urlByEnvironment()">{{ 'main.flow-contact-link' | translate }}</a>
```

You can't wrap the pipe `translate` with quotation, otherwise it will be considered a string.